# How do I Trim between 2 doors that are close together?

Tags: trim, carpentry, door-frame, trim-carpentry, jamb

I need to install jamb on the strike opening of my second pocket door and trim out both. I'm stuck because it looks a bit stupid to me, the doors are to close to each other to trim each out normally between them. The jamb is 3/4" and the trim is 1/2" thick so I will have a step between them if I butt them together. (see 2nd photo of both pieces leaned against the wall).

Solution I have thought of:

Since I have 8 1/2" from the edge on the left to the end of the right door jamb, I was thinking that buying a single piece of primed 1X10 and ripping it to width to cover the trim on the door to the right and the jamb on the left door with the same piece. I would obviously need to notch the top and put a 45 on the right top edge to meet the trim on the right door, but then I ran into the same issue, the thickness where the board and trim meet on the 45. See below photo (red is 1"x10', blue is 3 1/2" trim, yellow circle is the thickness difference.)

The right door also has 5 inch base board that needs to run along the wall on the right side.(same thickness as trim)

My question is does the solution I proposed seem like the right way, if not, what would be a better solution?

[image: proposed trim]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Your images don't appear. Please post them using the Mountain Icon on the Edit function.

Comment: @Triplefault fixed them. added some edits.

Comment: Somehow, posting images gets to be a struggle sometimes. I think that SE sites use a slightly different format than other sites do, so when people try to add images by hand, they get _oh so close but no cigar_. Use the "sun & mountain" icon above the text box to add images or just drag'n drop them into the edit box. I've patched them up to use the SE formatting so they'll even appear properly for those who use screen readers or who can't get to imgur...

Comment: @FreeMan it seems that copying the image link directly from Imgur does not add the picture extension,  and also doesn't work using the mountain icon, I had to add .jpeg to the end of each link for them to show up

Comment: Are these both pocket doors?

Comment: Weird, @JustSomeGuy. I've not run into that. Maybe it's a new requirement...

Comment: What about planing down the 1x10 so it's 1/2" thick? Then it will match thickness to the trim piece like you were planning in the red/blue/yellow markup.

Comment: @Huesmann yes, they both are.

Comment: @Triplefault this is an option too, and probably what I will do unless someone has a better approach.

Comment: Your 10x idea seems fine.  Why can't you just use the same thickness for everything? You haven't explained that so it's hard to know what a good solution would be.  The baseboard doesn't have to be the same thickness. Join the baseboard to the trim by extending the thicker one and having the thinner one butt up against its side.  If your problem is that the slider requires 3/4 and you have other doors with half inch trim you want to match, I think you use 3/4 here, match it as well as you can in all other respects, it will look fine.